# Django delete an object from within one of its own methods

Tags: python, django, generic-foreign-key

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    parent_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='prereq_parent')
    parent_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    parent_object = GenericForeignKey("parent_content_type", "parent_object_id")

    ...

    def get_parent(self):
       try:
           return self.parent_content_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=self.parent_object_id)
       except ObjectDoesNotExist:
           #do something that will result in this instance of MyModel to be deleted
```

it will break if the foreign key is deleted, so instead of breaking, I am catching it when a needed foreign key has been deleted.  When this happens, how do I delete this entire instance of MyModel, and then carry on.

Comment: [`self.delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete)?

Answer (score 0):

Before you deleted your Foreign Class:

```
foreign = ForeignClass.objects.get(pk=id)
myModel = MyModel.objects.filter(content_object=foreign)
myModel.delete()
foreign.delete()
```

Hope this works for you.